# Keep getting error 500, php file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I keep getting error 500 when trying to get a very large file with php,

```
$get_file = file_get_contents("../../test/test.mp4", true); // the size of .mp4 is more than 2GB
echo $get_file;
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

My php.ini file isset to handle 4000 MB, (I'm not sure if php even can handle that much)..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)

And since `file_get_contents` returns a string... ;)

Instead, use [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to retrieve a file pointer resource and [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read data portionally.